# why fourier transform multiplies $e^{-i\omega t}$ not $e^{i\omega t}$?

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform

I think that difference between $e^{-i\omega t}$ and $e^{i\omega t}$ is only the direction of rotation.

Is there any reason why Fourier Transform multiplies $e^{-i\omega t}$ and Inverse Fourier Transform multiplies $e^{i\omega t}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

When calculating the transform of $s(t) = e^{j\omega_0 t}$, we'd like to see an impulse at frequency $\omega_0$. The way the transform is conventionally defined, that is what we get:
$$
\hat{f}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty s(x) e^{-j\omega x} dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{j \omega_0 x} e^{-j\omega x} dx
$$
which is indeed an impulse when $\omega = \omega_0$ and zero elsewhere. If we had defined the transform with an exponent $j \omega x$ instead, we'd get an impulse at $\omega = -\omega_0$.

So, even though the math works either way, having the forward transform use $-j \omega x$ is a useful convention.

Comment: +1 As it is the best out of the three answers thus far. It shows why the convention is the way it is AND why mathematically it doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: @AhsanYousaf To be clear, he is saying that it DOES make a difference. For the case of real signals it doesn't make a difference due to Hermitian symmetry but for complex signals there would be a spectrum reversal, as MBaz articulates.

Comment: To make an (imperfect) analogy: it'd be like changing the sign of all numbers. Arithmetic still works, all theorems are still true, but now when you're hungry you have to say "I'd like to have minus one sandwich".

Comment: I like that! Very good analogy. So yes all the same as long as we're happy with putting the positive going frequencies to the left in the result. Probably a relief to the left-handed people out there.

Comment: @DanBoschen Yes, I understand that but does that *really* make a difference. To a person who understands the theory and the maths behind it, a reversed spectrum, albeit inconvenient, still contains all the information as the usual spectrum. So, for example, people approaching this from a purely mathematical perspective don't really care to always define it with the same convention that us electrical engineers do because they don't usually care about looking at it in the frequency domain. I say this because I have seen a lot of my math major friends do this...

Comment: Right, as long as you know the info is there, similar to how it doesn’t make a difference if the signal is at baseband or a 1 GHz carrier. So yes I see your point. To someone that does work in the frequency domain it is an important distinction and the choise of using a negative sign is consistent with the need for a complex conjugate in a complex correlation, so makes sense in that regard too.

Answer (score 1):

For those familiar with radio receivers and mixing as a product of the signal with a local oscillator, you can think of the FT as a down-converting receiver with an integration as the matched filter (which is optimum for constant level signals in the presence of white noise). The product of an arbitrary signal $x(t)$ with $e^{-j\omega t}$ translates the signal from a carrier at $\omega$ to DC. Consider if we had a signal that was a tone exactly at $\omega$, this would be given as:

$$x(t) = e^{j\omega t}$$

The down-conversion is done with a product, and to properly frequency translate the signal to DC, it needs to be complex conjugate multiplication:

$$x(t)e^{-j\omega t} = e^{j\omega t}e^{-j\omega t} = 1$$

Thus our constant signal as a tone at $\omega$ becomes a constant at DC ($1$!). To complete what is a correlation operation, we integrate, and thus the result will grow to infinity assuming the signal was indeed at $\omega$, resulting in the expected impulse as a result!

I find it helpful especially with the FT to view $e^{j\omega t}$ as a single "tone", and sinusoids such as $\cos(\omega t)$ to be composed of two tones, a positive and negative tone. This is exactly what the Fourier Transform shows us as the resulting impulses in the frequency domain for the FT of $\cos(\omega t)$ as well as given by Euler's relationship:

$$2\cos(\omega t) = e^{j\omega t} + e^{-j\omega t}$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the simplest of signals
$$Aexp(i\omega t)$$
If you want to remove the oscillation to extract the $A$, which is, in effect what a Fourier transform lets you do, you need to multiply by $\exp(-i\omega t)$ to cancel out the $exp(i\omega t)$. And when you want the inverse Fourier transform you're going to want to multiply by $exp(i\omega t)$ to put it back on again.

Answer (score 1):

Lot's of good answers here, figure I'd add another perspective.

You can view the Fourier Transform as a matched filterbank. Matched filters perform correlations. If you want to find the cross-correlation between two signals, you convolve the one signal with the time-reversed complex conjugate of the other signal. Expressing this we have:

\begin{equation} (x*h)(\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)h(\tau-t)) dt \end{equation}

\begin{equation} R_{x,h}(\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)h^{*}(t-\tau) dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)h^{*}(-(\tau-t)) \end{equation}

From the first equation, we can see that if we convolve our signal $x(t)$ with $h(t) = e^{j\omega t}$, the correlation equation becomes the Fourier transform with a phase offset. This is shown by

\begin{equation} R_{x,h}(\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)e^{-j\omega(t-\tau)}dt = e^{j\omega\tau}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)e^{-j\omega t}\end{equation}

In the computation of the Fourier transform, we really only care about the frequency content, not the exact temporal location of the signal, so the phase offset is excluded to get

\begin{equation} X(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)e^{-j\omega t}\end{equation}